# Using selectors with csQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, csquery

I am very new to csQuery and I am having a difficult time getting off the ground. The following is my simple asp.net controller. It is returning the following: $('.ng-scope').eq(0).find($('.ng-binding')).html(). The classes referenced do exist. Am I doing this right?

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ViewModel Vm = new ViewModel();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var url = "http://www.weather.com/weather/5day/l/08817:4:US";
        var web = new WebClient();
        web.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Hello"; //in case they require it
        var html = web.DownloadString(url);
        CQ dom = html;
        var x = dom["$('.ng-scope').eq(0).find($('.ng-binding')).html()"];

        Vm.Day = x.Render();
        return View(Vm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the code working or encountering an error of some kind?

Comment: Or are you saying that the view itself outputs the string "$('.ng-scope').eq(0).find($('.ng-binding')).html()"?

Comment: The view outputs that string.

Comment: Ok.  What does your view look like?

Comment: Simple like so: @model EasyWeather.Models.ViewModel

<p>@Model.Day</p>

Comment: Great, could you put that in the question? And also add ViewModel's definition?  That should give all the parts needed for someone else to reproduce issue.

Comment: If I had the ViewModel, I could work on reproducing this.  I can fake something up, but that might not be as effective.

Comment: sorry for late response. Here's the view model:     public class ViewModel
    {
        public string Day { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DWright, you're absolutely correct! After analyzing it again myself, I realized that the classes i'm referring to are dynamically created but don't exist in the source.I'll have to trace the DOM back to the caller and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

So, first thing is that you the selector is in jQuery syntax, and needs to be adapted for csQuery, to something like: `dom[".ng-scope"].Eq(0).Find(".ng-binding").Html();`

Second I put the url in a browser and then looked at the source.  There was a not a single element with a class of `"ng-scope"`.  So I think you need to analyze the source of the page you are downloading so that you can reformulate the query.